# Do VBA questions belong on SO or SU?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Questions involving using VBA to do some advanced task in Outlook or Word seem like they belong on Super User, but I'm not entirely sure.  I think questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287247/how-can-i-use-outlook-restict-method-to-filter-the-outlook-items-on-lastmodificat) straddle the line between the two sites, and could possibly be asked on both.  What does everyone else think?  Should questions like this be migrated to one site or the other, or just left where they're originally posted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe it is a judgement call based on each question. I have passed a few VBA question on SU, which based on the **way** it was asked indicates the user is simply a power user and needs gentle guidance, compared to the question in your example that shows some throrough research on the topic. This is what I use as my guide. If the question requires developer level understanding --> SO, if not --> SU.

My vote:

**Based on the level and quality of the question, leave it where it was posted, unless it will get a better response somewhere else.**

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question, but I think a good rule of thumb would be based upon if what you are trying to accomplish could be recorded or not. If you have to actually hand write the macro then I would say it belongs on Stack Overflow. However, if you are able to just use the macro recorder and go through a series of menu commands then I would say that it belongs on Super User.

Comment: Thanks.  Recording vs. writing macros by hand is a really good point that I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good example of a question that belongs on both sites.  See here: [Allow cross-posting of questions to more than one SO site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/allow-cross-posting-of-questions-to-more-than-one-so-site)

Comment: Thanks.  Questions on vi (as you linked to previously), emacs, and LaTeX are examples of other topics that seem to straddle that line.

Comment: Questions about `vi`, belong on awesomeoverflow.com Questions about `emacs` belong on fingertwitching.com

Comment: No, it isn't a good example of a question that belongs on both sites. If its a developer trying to automate something for an app, department, company, etc. it belongs on SO. If its a power user working in the context of a personal project (work or home) it belongs on SU.

Comment: emacs: it's finger-twitchin' good!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on context.

- If its a developer trying to automate something for an app, department, company, etc. it belongs on SO.
- If its a power user working in the context of a personal project (work or home) it belongs on SU.

Comment: @Rob: Possibly, but more often than not those people will be programmers and are more likely to ask on SO anyway. In the rare case that doesn't apply, its not like it can't be moved.