# Relevance of question regarding excel but not related to programming

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723492/how-to-edit-my-excel-dropdown-list) question (tagged with [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and [excel2003](/questions/tagged/excel2003)) a bit ago.

It has nothing to do with programming, so I voted to close as off-topic and suggested it be migrated to Super User.

Am I justified in this? Or am I misunderstanding the scope of the site completely in terms of software?

And if I am justified, is Super User the right place for it?

The reason I ask is because it hasn't been downvoted, there were no previous close votes cast, and it even has a few answers with one accepted. All this happened *after* Super User launched in September '09.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct in observing that it's not programming-related. An Office VBA question might be on topic for Stack Overflow, but even those [are accepted on Super User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25676/do-vba-questions-belong-on-so-or-su) as well.

...But the one you found not a very good question in general, so it's probably not a good candidate for migration elsewhere in the network. Remember that rule number one of migration is [*"don't
migrate crap"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/153008).

Additionally, this is a very old question from way back in 2009, and we generally try not to migrate really old questions to other sites unless the site specifically requests those questions.

Therefore, I would just vote to close this one as "off-topic" without selecting a particular migration path.

In general, though, Super User *is* the place for general software-related questions. From their [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#questions):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!