# Slight Amendment to Close Reason

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

> Questions **asking for code** must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

A small request i.e if it's possible to incorporate.

Can the above bold line be changed to **asking for code/formula**

We have Excel-Formula tag where we get lot of questions where people simply demand for formulas without trying anything and the above message then doesn't make sense.

**EDIT**: Perhaps `only` discussing in comments or `only` downvoting constantly, some one might considering putting an answer together? I could then mark that as an answer????? This is so that if I close the question in SO using the above and if someone questions, I can re-direct them to this thread?

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this but isn't an excel formula a form of very light weight code?

Comment: No a code is very different from a formula and vice versa

Comment: If they weren't code, then writing them wouldn't be programming and the questions would be off topic.

Comment: They shouldn't be using the `excel-formula` tag, they should be using the `worksheet-function` tag, but that's another issue.

Comment: There is a very thin line between Code and Formula and hence Excel-Formula were always considered a borderline between SO and SU.

Comment: Excel formulas are definitely code, just in a different format.

Comment: I seem to recall that excel formulas in fact are off topic; see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194726/why-is-there-an-excel-formulas-tag), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spreadsheet-formulas-belong-on) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123366/relevance-of-question-regarding-excel-but-not-related-to-programming)

Comment: No, they are on-topic, and always have been.

Comment: Exactly my point Richard/Lance They are considered borderline between SO and SU. I would respectfully disagree that a Formula is a Code. Yes the formulas are written in C++ but that doesn't mean that the formula is same or similar to code.

Comment: @LanceRoberts References? (Not saying you're wrong, but references are always nice). I was under the impression VBA --> stack overflow, Formulas --> Super user

Comment: @RichardTingle. In the second example you've provided there is an answer with score 27 that says Excel is ok in both sites. The accepted (score:20) answer does not come from a mod or a dev.

Comment: @RichardTingle, look at the most upvoted answer on all those links, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76767/13295

Comment: @RichardTingle: See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) there are already 1671 questions tagged and they are very much valid for SO.

Comment: Regardless, there are two reasonable positions (1) functions **are** a kind of code and so are on topic on stack overflow, (2) functions **are not** a kind of code and so are off topic. Neither of these interpretations require a change in the close reason. Are you arguing (3) Functions are not code, yet are on topic at stack overflow because ......

Comment: @RichardTingle: No I am not arguing. I don't like arguing. I am always up for a healthy discussion though. Hope you know the difference between the two?

Comment: *sigh* arguing a position is not the same as having an argument. Regardless, which **position** are you taking, 1,2 or 3?

Comment: @RichardTingle: A discussion is more like a debate... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47064/whats-the-difference-between-debate-and-argument. But then that is not the intention of this post. I am still not convinced that Code and Formulas are the same or similar

Comment: So position 3 then? "Functions are not code, yet are on topic at stack overflow because ......"

Comment: because... They can do fine on either site SO or SU

Comment: Anyways with `-4` downvotes.. I rest my case....

Comment: I'm sure a pure maths question would do fine on stack overflow as well (if it wasn't closed), stack overflow is for programming, either it is or it isn't programming

Comment: Can we also add "markup" to the list of things that you can't ask for without showing an effort, because HTML is even less code than Excel formulas are.

Comment: +1 to the question. Because there are many scenarios in Excel that can be solved either by coding or formula logic or by clicking a few icons on the ribbon. Sometimes it's not the QUESTION that is off-topic, but the ANSWER. If Joe asks how to do red-amber-green traffic lights in Excel, the answer can be to use code, or to use a conditional formatting formula (which is like code) or to click a few icons and follow-on options in dialogs. According to the commonly accepted framework, the code answer would make this question on topic, whereas the  ribbon-click answer would make it off topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If excel questions are on topic at all (a debated topic) then it is because excel formulas are considered code. As such the existing close reason is sufficient to close these questions.

Adding this would open a "can of worms" of other additions, for example as Wooble has mentioned; is a mark up language such as HTML "code"?

Comment: I will wait for an hour. If no one else posts an answer, I will accept your answer..

Comment: I approve that choice, someone who strongly believed that excel questions are on topic could probably write a better answer. I think that you highlighted a legitimate problem (people saying "but its not code, you can't close it"), I disagree with the proposed solution only

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated.