# Allow cross-posting of questions to more than one meta site

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, per-site-meta, site-crossover

With the rise of more scientific sites; such as Physics, Chemistry, Biology, and Computational Science, I find myself wondering where I should post about using scientific software for biophysicists.

Along the lines of the [main-site cross-post idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/allow-cross-posting-of-questions-to-more-than-one-so-site); I propose some mechanism to allow users to perform cross-meta-site posts.  This would increase awareness among users that may be interested in the outcome of a given discussion, even if it's happening on another site's meta.

This is somewhat in the spirit of Area51 discussions; where if you [link multiple proposals](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/merge-beer-and-wine-include-spirits-liquor) (not sure exactly how it works) in a discussion post, it shows up on [both](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2377/beer) [proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28675/wine).

I think status quo now for anything non-trivial is to notify the other site and point back to the original discussion, but this could fragment the thread (people posting and commenting on two, or more, sites), or not involve the other community until later in the process.  One post to Rule Them All™ seems desirable.

Here are some awful ideas on this theme:  It could be restricted to it's "neighbors" (e.g. the sites I listed in my example, which are perhaps the known migration paths), or simply open to everything.  MSO could be everything's neighbor (or not, to reduce noise).  Maybe it could work like a fake reverse-migrated question that still shows up on the "source" site.

Comment: A related feature req: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration . Sort of like your fake-reverse-migrate, but neater

Comment: Personally, the fact that you would even *want* to do this shows a problem with having separate Physics, Chemistry, Biology, etc sites.

Comment: @NicolBolas what problem is that?  It seems [unavoidable](http://xkcd.com/435/).

Comment: @NickT: The problem is that they shouldn't have been separate sites to begin with. It should have just been "Science Overflow". Then you could just ask, with appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1):

SE Corporate monitors *all* of the meta sites.  You only need to make your post on one.

If your question has broad applicability to all (or a substantial portion of) the SE sites, post it here.  If your particular community is primarily involved in the question, or the question is only applicable to one meta site, post it to the site-specific meta.

Cross posting to multiple metas *is not necessary,* unless you're trying to coordinate a meta communication between two SE sites.  In those rare instances, copy/paste should suffice.

Comment: He's talking about posting on their meta-sites. He wants to know if a question would be appropriate on a particular site, and he wants to ask many of them at once.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks.  I'll fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure; are you talking about meta question/discussions?  The issue isn't the initial post ("question"), it's the fragmented follow-on discussion

Comment: I don't see (for example) my question about scientific software being well-answered here.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @NickT: What?  Why are you asking questions about scientific software on meta sites?

Comment: @RobertHarvey not on the technical side but more the topicality of it and where such questions would belong--namely where are the experts (as one of but many possible examples)

Comment: That kind of question is best asked here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see myself asking the question and getting answers that are completely unhelpful as the bureaucracy here would likely have no practical knowledge and simply legislate based on theory.  I'll give it a whirl at some point and let you know.